# Unable to select vertices, edges and faces since upgrade to windows 10

Tags: modeling, selection-tools

I'm a newbie both to here and to blender. I have a problem in so much as since Windows 10 auto installed yesterday I am now unable to work on my current project.

Problem is: I am unable to select either vertices, faces or edges when in edit mode as usual. Works normally if using box select.

If anyone can help it will be appreciated. I'm 82 and self taught, so not too complicated an answer would be great.

Comment: If you just upgraded to windows 10 make sure you upgrade the drivers for your graphics card as well (and that those drivers are indeed compatible with windows 10)

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! It's great to have new people. Don't forget to earn some reputation by taking the tour (http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) so that you can unlock more privileges. I've been using Windows 10 for quite a while now, without any problems, so I'm really interested to find out what the problem is.

Comment: Lesrae, it would be helpful to know more about your system, particularly whether it is a desktop or laptop. Also, more detail about how you are trying to make the selection would be useful.

Comment: I am using a Toshiba satalite C855-1GQ laptop.When I try to select a pixel,edge or face they don't change color or show the X,Y,Z indicator.When I use B to box select everything seems to work normally highlighting pixels etc. and the XYZ indicator is also back.I am stuck please help.Les